# The Area of Card Required to Make a Cone

Tags: geometry, area

The solution of the question I'm trying to understand is this:

[image]

The part of the solution I don't understand is "the area of card needed for each hat (cone) is $\frac{1}{2}r^2$", because I would think that the area of the card required to make one cone would just be the area of one sector which would just be $\frac{1}{6}\pi r^2$. So, I'm wondering what exactly the area of card required to make the cone would be in here and how it is found.

Comment: The area of 1 sector is not $\frac{1}{6}πr^2$ because there is some cardboard left over after 6 hats are made. The area given is probably derived from the surface area of a cone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [area of a sector of a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector) is $\frac12rL$ where $r$ is the radius of the circle and $L$ is the arc length (along the circle's circumference) of the sector. For your example the value of $L$ for each hat is $r$.